# JQuery Validation with Knockout If Binding

Tags: knockout.js, jquery-validate, unobtrusive-validation

I have a simple form for ordering goods.
On my form I have a check box which toggles whether a separate billing address is required to the delivery address.
The billing address controls are hidden using the Knockout if binding.

I'm using using Microsoft Unobtrusive JQuery Validation to validate my controls.
Unfortunately the validation for the billing controls does not work - no validation messages are displayed, I'm guessing because they do not exist at the point that JQuery Validation does it's 'binding'.   Is there some way of reloading the JQuery validation?

Comment: A simple solution is to use the `visible` binding instead of the `if` binding. I believe that the `visible` binding will still add your markup to the DOM, just with `display: none`. That way, your validation should still work. If you're using the `if` binding, then you'd have to reapply the validation.

Comment: Would that not give me the inverse problem.  If address is not being shown the items would still be validated? Thanks

Comment: I've just tried it and no it doesn't.  JQuery validate must be smart enough to know not to do that.  Thanks Patrick

Comment: Please show some relevant code.

Comment: Why? There's no code that's broken.  The question was as to whether there's a method to reload the JQuery Validation given the situation described.  Patricks Answer is also correct.